# Error in Datepicker on Android, not show well

Tags: android, datepicker

I'm trying to open a dialog for picking a date in fragment on Android.

```
linDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
            newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");   }
 });
```

and i have this inner class:

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
    }
}
```

the problem is that the date picker not show well: [image: like this pic]

i use xiaomi redmi note 4x to run my app.
in the emulator that works fine.

my style.xml : https://pastebin.com/8dFXSa0A

Comment: hii nadav tamim can you please post your current style.xml 
i have implement this code on my device LOLIPOP it works proper

Comment: i added my style.xml

Comment: your asking for my style.xml Direct me to search the problem there and i found it, it was the android:gravity">center that makes the problem.
thank you!

Comment: okk and u also try my code and check it for you batter picker  dialog view and also you give me up vote or right mark if u have not a problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply open datepicker and select and set date in edittext by using below code;

```
EditText from_date;
String date;

  final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    date = String.valueOf(dayOfMonth<10?("0"+dayOfMonth):(dayOfMonth)) +"-"+String.valueOf((monthOfYear+1)<10?("0"+(monthOfYear+1)):(monthOfYear+1))
                            +"-"+String.valueOf(year);
                    from_date.setText(date);
                }
            }, yy, mm, dd);
            datePicker.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void openDatePicker() {
        //clearing error if any
        tvdate.setError(null);//it is textview
        final Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(Getaddressforlaundry.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy", Locale.US);
                dateString = sdf.format(newDate.getTime());
                if (newCalendar.getTimeInMillis() < newDate.getTimeInMillis()) {
                    tvdate.setText(dateString);//it is textview
                    tvdate.setTag(null);//it is textview
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Getaddressforlaundry.this, getString(R.string.feature_date_selected), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    tvdate.setTag("false");//it is textview
                    tvdate.setError(getString(R.string.feature_date_selected));
                }

            }
        }, newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(newCalendar.getTimeInMillis());
        datePickerDialog.show();


    }
```